# DC motor turns ON itself

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, opto-isolator, motor-controller, isolation

I am driving a DC motor with driver [DRV8871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf) and using optocoupler [SHARP PC817](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Downloads/PC817%20optocoupler.pdf) for the logic pin to the driver for isolating motor supply & MCU supply.

[image]

I noticed very weird behaviour of the motor: it runs perfectly when I run it through giving PWM from MCU, but sometimes if I am not giving any signal to the optocoupler it still runs by itself and after some time it stops or runs continuously at full speed, even after giving specific PWM from the MCU. I measured the Signal applied to the optocoupler through multimeter when I am not giving any signal from MCU or MCU is off and reading of voltage iS negligible so it won’t turn optocoupler LED ON but I measured voltage at the output side (phototransistor side of optocoupler) and voltage is around 4-5V

What could be the possible reason? Is the optocoupler giving a false signal? Please help!!

Comment: Do you consider that your schematic is not important?

Comment: `I am not giving any signal to the optocoupler` ... how do you know that this statement is true?

Comment: @jsotola because motor still keeps moving with full speed even supply for my MCU is off

Comment: @Andyaka optocoupler schematic attached in the question forgive me if I have not done that in better way

Comment: When the MCU is off, what actual signal is applied to the optocoupler? You may need to empirically measure it since not all MCUs have predictable behavior when turned off but connected to powered external peripherals.

Comment: @nanofarad I measured the Signal applied to the optocoupler through multimeter when I am not giving any signal from MCU or MCU is off and reading of voltage id negligible so it won’t turn optocoupler LED ON but I measured voltage at the output side (phototransistor side of optocoupler) and voltage is around 4.5V

Comment: @NavneetPandey the motor driver had pulldown resistors at its inputs ... your circuit has pullup resistors that have inconsistent values ... perhaps one of them has a value that causes the problem .... remove the pullup resistors and put the opto there instead

Comment: Please [edit] that clarification into your post.

Comment: According to your circuit, when the opto is **off**, you *should* have ~5V in the output of the opto.  When the opto is **on** then the output should be near 0V.

Comment: Remove the connection to the MCU and switch it by hand. Another test could be to replace the motor with a resistor, check the current/voltage with a DMM.

Comment: It's quite possible that you've damaged your motor driver chip.  But since you've left it out of your question, this is unanswerable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have 3 PCB board all are acting same and  I didn’t do anything which damage the motor driver

Comment: You can have no such certainty; self activation is a prime symptom of damage.  That's not to say that it's necessarily what is wrong, but you have absolutely no basis to rule it out.  And without the details of your motor drive setup in the question, nor measurements of the actual motor drive inputs in the situation where this occurs, there's no way for anyone to comment on the likelihood of damage, either.

Comment: 4.5V suggest Rc is only 10% of probe or load Impedance

Comment: @Aaron Yes, when motor at full speed voltage is 0.111vdc and when it lowest speed (PWM) voltage is 4.198VDC

Answer (score 0):

Your fault is using D3,D4 which puts the LED in a high impedance state prone to stray EMI.

Try and 10k shunt resistor across the LED. If that works.OK but D3,D4 is your problem.  If you wish to protect the LED’s from -5V no need. But if you used 24V with 1K then use D3 in reverse bias across LED instead so that’s stray CM noise does not cause false triggers.

Then your input when connected is never floating.

Some parts have CTR as high as 600 which only needs 1mA/600 input current to trigger at line speeds. Your Probe may also work to suppress this but pay attention to crosstalk from Motor current to the input CM stray coupling with shielded STP wire or UN shielded UTP twisted pair at right angles to motor wires which should also be twisted pair.

This can be explained further with a photo of your layout.

Comment: So you are saying that the opto LEDs can emit light due to EMI?

Comment: Stray EMI can't keep an LED lit. They're not like MOSFET gates.

Comment: True yet driving MOSFET gates. maybe the wrong  Rc was used like 500k.  then it’s easy to trigger with 50V Efield to draw 200uA x6 . What do you suggest? @user253751